# Why can't I build a Flutter project for iOS with transitive dependencies and statically linked binaries, yet other project with same setup works fine?

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods, podfile, pubspec

I've got 2 Flutter projects, with the same:

- Podfile
- `pubspec.yaml` dependency list
- Flutter version 3.3.7

One compiles, the other doesn't with the error:

```
 - Running pre install hooks
    [!] The 'Pods-Runner' target has transitive dependencies that include statically linked binaries:
    (/Users/daveshirman/Documents/Work/scy/ios/Pods/Mux-Stats-AVPlayer/XCFramework/MUXSDKStats.xcframework)
```

I've tried:

- Reinstalling cocoapods (now at 1.11.3)
- Deleting pods folder + ios/Flutter folder + pub get
- flutter clean multiple times
- Deleting Podfile.lock
- pod repo update
- etc

None of these are working.  I've seen some suggestions to add extra commands to the Podfile to ignore the error, but that seems like a workaround, not a solution.

Seeing as my 2 projects are set up the same, they should both compile with the same Podfile.

**So...Any ideas?**

**Note**: Please don't mark this as a duplicate.  I've seen other questions similar, but none referncing the same linked library and none of their solutions have worked for me thus far.

**Here's my Podfile in case:**

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

# post_install do |installer|
#   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
#     flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
#   end
# end

target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'OneSignalXCFramework', '>= 3.4.3', '< 4.0'
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)

    target.build_configurations.each do |config|

      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
     
      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
        '$(inherited)',
         'PERMISSION_PHOTOS=1',
         'PERMISSION_MEDIA_LIBRARY=1',
      ]

    end
  end
end
```